# Asks user to input floating-point values. If invalid inputs more than twice, quit the program using python

Tags: python, input, floating-point, sum

I have to make a function that requests non-zero floating-point values from the user; when the user enters 0, the sum of the numbers input is printed. The function terminates when the user enters two invalid inputs in a row.

I have the following code:

```
def inValues():
    counter = 0
    s = 0

    while True:
        if counter <= 2:
            try:
                digit = input('Please enter a number: ')
                counter += 1
                floatDig = float(digit)
                break
        else:
            break
        except:
            print('Error. Please re-enter the value.')
    if floatDig == 0:
        s += sum(floatDig)
        return s
```

But when ran, it asks for one input only, then stops. I'm pretty sure the code is pretty scrambled and broken so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Take out the `try:` then try it again

Comment: wait why do you have a `try` then an `except` at different indents that is odd

Comment: There is a problem with your indentation. The else refers to the if and should be at the same level, the except refers to the try and should be at the same level. Then, you will see that you cannot mix them like you do. The except should follow the try block.

Comment: good comments don't tell what; they explain why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few notes:

- A `while` loop can have a condition - so I use it for the error counting
- The `break` exits the `while` loop - so I removed it (we now use it for monitoring error count).
- I immediately check if the user wants to quit
- The error counter is only increased on error.

Code:

```
def inValues():
    errorcounter = 0
    s = 0

    while errorcounter < 2: # errorcounter = [0, 1] ...
        digit = input('Please enter a number: ')
        if digit == '0':
            # return sum of numbers
            return s
        try:
            # try and summarize input
            s += float(digit)
        except:
            print('Error. Please re-enter the value.')
            errorcounter += 1

    print("Too many errors.")
    # possibly return indicative value (None?)
```